# Dynamic web page scraping in php

Tags: php, web-scraping, web-crawler, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I am trying chrome-php/chrome library to read the dynamicaly rendered web pages, but it's returning nothing. I am using php version 8.0.

This is what I have implemented [I have followed the documentation] -

```
use HeadlessChromium\BrowserFactory;

$browserFactory = new BrowserFactory();

// starts headless chrome
$browser = $browserFactory->createBrowser('/opt/google/chrome/chrome');

try {
    // creates a new page and navigate to an URL
    $page = $browser->createPage();
    $page->navigate('http://example.com')->waitForNavigation();

    // get page title
    $pageTitle = $page->evaluate('document.title')->getReturnValue();

    echo $pageTitle;

} finally {
    // bye
    $browser->close();
}
```

It's not returning the title of the url I am trying to read. can you help me to debug this issue?

Comment: What errors do you get? Either on CLI or, if this is executed inside a web server then in your http server's error log file ...

Comment: i am not getting any error.

Comment: Did you _really_ check in your http server's error log file? What does it contain?

Comment: I think you need to have chrome installed on the server for this to work. Iv used puppeteer before and it required chrom browser installed for it to work

Comment: @arkascha There is no error logged for today's date.. all are the old logs.

Answer (score 2):

Before doing the modifications, put this on your script to make it show errors:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Probably the error is on this line:
This method doesn't accept a string.

```
$browser = $browserFactory->createBrowser('/opt/google/chrome/chrome');
```

You must pass the google chrome executable to:

```
$browserFactory = new BrowserFactory('/opt/google/chrome/chrome');
```

or just leave it blank and the system will use the default location:

```
$browserFactory = new BrowserFactory();
```

Comment: The default location is throwing error, that's why i have passed the location as argument.

Comment: Got it working?

just remove the path from createbrowser and put on the browser factory method.

$browserFactory = new BrowserFactory('/opt/google/chrome/chrome');
$browser = $browserFactory->createBrowser();

Comment: It really is questionable to advise to enable the `display_errors` feature. That is not how error reporting and debugging should be done now. It breaks the UI, creates chaos, it makes much more sense to monitor the error log file. That's what log files are for.

Comment: @arkascha, yes, you're right. But the suggestion was only to debug the code, as the OP was not finding the log file. The code as posted is throwing errors because the createBrowser() doesn't accept strings.